# Not allow users to select the same date. PHP, MYSQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am attempting to not allow the users to place orders on the same day. My SQL and PHP does not return an error from this code. However, it does not return anything, or even place the order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    //Check if the date has been taken
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date='$date'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 1) { 
        header("Location: ../placeorder.php?order=taken");
        exit();
    } else { 
        header("Location: ../placeorder.php");
        exit(); 
    }
}

//Insert orders into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id, price, time, date, type, square_ft, materials ) VALUES ('$userid','$price', '$time', '$date', '$type', '$square_ft','$materials' );";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../placeorder.php?=order=success");
exit();
```

Comment: Can't you make the column _unique_?

Comment: [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) _Returns number of rows in the result set._. So shouldn't we be checking this instead `$resultCheck > 0`?

Comment: "My SQL and PHP does not return an error from this code." -- you're not *checking* for an error from mysql

Comment: I've fixed it. All I needed to do was remove the else statement after $resultCheck, it seems to work fine now. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was remove the else statement after the $resultCheck. Plus set ($resultCheck > 0).

```
        //Check if the date has been taken
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date='$date'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultCheck > 0) { 
                    header("Location: ../placeorder.php?order=taken");
                    exit();
                } 
    }

    //Insert orders into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id, price, time, date, type, square_ft, materials ) VALUES ('$userid','$price', '$time', '$date', '$type', '$square_ft','$materials' );";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../placeorder.php?=order=success");
                exit();
```

}